# OpenCV detect liquid level in a tube

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have image like this below

[image: tube]

Can anyone suggest how to detect the level of the liquid?
Is this too blurry to process? I have tried Canny and findContour and cannot detect the line.

[image]

I am using python opencv 4.8

Comment: convert image to black and white, then sharpen the image, then check for the color to change in intensity (from dark to light) then use a threshold value to control when its triggered, use a 30x8pixel block for detection, at the desired point on the line you want to check

Comment: maintain the same lighting for your tube, so you wont have to adjust anything

Comment: i also suggest that you have your base line, and then another line above it about 1, or 2 cm, this way you have a detection line and an overflow line.

Comment: also I suggest that you take a least 10 frames (at 60fps) and do a difference, in case you have something dripping into it which can mess with the detection line

Comment: I have empty tube as baseline but the liquid level is just too blur.

Comment: play with a flashlight. what can you do to make this line show up as a stronger contrast?